# what is the problem in my reqular expression

Tags: python, regex, string, search, match

i am trying to extract the phone but the expression returns none.
here is my code.it must start with 9 and end with number with only number inbetween.

```
line='my phone is 98849448470'
matchnum=re.search(r"^9[0-9]*[0-9]$",line)
print(matchnum)
```

Comment: Not clear, trying to match a 3 digit number?

Comment: I think you want word breaks rather than start/end of line anchors: `r"\b9[0-9]*[0-9]\b"`

Comment: hey guys why do u downvote anytime.anyway how do i format my code that like that.its annoying i can't do it.

Comment: thank you,this is the solution i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
matchnum=re.search(r"^9[0-9]*[0-9]$",line)
```

The `^` at the start and `$` at the end force the expression to try to match the entire `line`. However, your actual `line` contains other stuff besides what you want to search for. So leave those out.

Also, instead of `[0-9]*[0-9]` for one or more matches, we can simply use `[0-9]+`.

Comment: hi, i thought it would search inside the entire line and returns the value after finding it.i did't knew it checks the entire line.thanks anyway.i am newbie here making some mistake